# How to make styled components mixins with props as css property?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm building an app with React and Styled components. I'd like to use mixins inside the styles, and pass a CSS property inside this mixin. I tried like this but it's not working:

```
const TestMixin = ({ color, property }) => css`
    ${property}: ${color === "blue"
        ? "blue"
        : color === "green"
        ? "green"
        : "red"};

    &:hover {
        ${property}: ${color === "blue"
            ? "red"
            : color === "green"
            ? "blue"
            : "green"};
    }
`

const Container = styled.div`
    background-color: ${TestMixin({
        property: "background-color"
    })};
`
```

How could I make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't to pass CSS property as an object key. If you want to create a similar scss mixin you can only pass CSS values to the mixin. To set CSS mixin in **Container**, just use the mixin without CSS property.

```js
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const TestMixin = ({ color }) => css`
  background-color: ${color === 'blue' ? 'blue' : color === 'green' ? 'green' : 'red'};

  &:hover {
    background-color: ${color === 'blue' ? 'red' : color === 'green' ? 'blue' : 'green'};
  }
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  ${TestMixin({ color: 'blue' })};
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
`;

export const App = () => {
  return <Container>Some text</Container>;
};
```

Try this solution with **Container** and container props, it is more flexible and customizable. If you removed the props, the style will not be applied.

```js
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

interface Colors {
  color: string;
  hover: string;
}
interface Props {
  bgColor?: Colors;
  borderColor?: Colors;
  textColor?: Colors;
}

const bgMixin = (color: Colors) => css`
  background-color: ${color.color};
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${color.hover};
  }
`;

const borderMixin = (color: Colors) => css`
  border-color: ${color.color};
  &:hover {
    border-color: ${color.hover};
  }
`;
const textMixin = (color: Colors) => css`
  color: ${color.color};
  &:hover {
    color: ${color.hover};
  }
`;

const Container = styled.div<Props>`
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  ${({ bgColor }) => bgColor && bgMixin(bgColor)}
  ${({ textColor }) => textColor && textMixin(textColor)}

  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  ${({ borderColor }) =>
    borderColor
      ? borderMixin(borderColor)
      : css`
          border-color: transparent;
        `}
`;

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container
      bgColor={{ color: 'blue', hover: 'red' }}
      borderColor={{ color: 'red', hover: 'blue' }}
      textColor={{ color: 'white', hover: 'black' }}
    >
      Styled Components
    </Container>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Comment: That's what I want to avoid, because I have something like 20 different colors, which can either be as `background-color`, `color`, `border-color`, etc. But thanks for your answer, I'm just gonna create more than one mixin

Comment: @JulSeb42 You can create mixins for these three properties and pass some props through the component.

Comment: Yes I thought about that, but I preferred to take it the other way and do three mixins with `ColorsDefault`, `ColorsHover` and `ColorsActive`. This way I have less mixins (since I don't know how many properties I'll have in the end). Thanks anyway!